# PC and Mac treating raster brick input differently in R

Tags: raster, r, windows

All - this is likely an idiotic question, but, I've been working on developing some GIS code in R that interacts with an online source.  So, sprinkled in various places, I have

`myBrick <- brick("http://somesite.com/image.jpg", crs=proj)`

This works well and good. And then...I moved to a PC. And chaos ensued.  The issue is that `brick()` on a PC appends additional text to the filename. So, I get

`` Error in .local(.Object, ...):
`C:\path\to\my\working\director\http://somesite.com/image.jpg` does not exist in the file system ``

This is.... odd. Same identical code. Entering strings. Never referencing working directory.

What is going on here? What is `brick()` doing differently? How can I stop the madness?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Try `brick("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/master/vignettes/clipping-with-bounding-box_files/figure-markdown_github/Westminster.png")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error comes from rgdal, I believe, specifically as it calls `normalizePath`, which probably should be avoided for filenames starting with http or ftp.

```
normalizePath("http://somesite.com/image.jpg", mustWork=FALSE)
```

on windows leads to:

```
#[1] "E:\\home\\http:\\somesite.com\\image.jpg"
```

but on linux I see:

```
#[1] "http://somesite.com/image.jpg"
```

So on windows you may need to do something like:

```
url <- "http://somesite.com/image.jpg"
download.file(url, basename(url))
b <- brick( basename(url) )
```

Comment: This sounds like the problem...now to figure out a fix...

Comment: just added one option